# My Job wont interrupt on IScheduler.Interrupt

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I am trying to implement an `IInterruptableJob` interface so that I could stop my job.

This is how my job implementation looks like (taken from https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/master/src/Quartz.Examples/example7/InterruptExample.cs)

```
public class HelloJob : IInterruptableJob
    {
        // logging services
        private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(HelloJob));
        // has the job been interrupted?
        private bool _interrupted;
        // job name 
        private JobKey _jobKey;

        /// <summary>
        /// Called by the <see cref="IScheduler" /> when a <see cref="ITrigger" />
        /// fires that is associated with the <see cref="IJob" />.
        /// </summary>
        public virtual void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            _jobKey = context.JobDetail.Key;
            Log.InfoFormat("---- {0} executing at {1}", _jobKey, DateTime.Now.ToString("r"));

            try
            {
                // main job loop... see the JavaDOC for InterruptableJob for discussion...
                // do some work... in this example we are 'simulating' work by sleeping... :)

                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(10 * 1000);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ignore)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ignore.StackTrace);
                    }

                    // periodically check if we've been interrupted...
                    if (_interrupted)
                    {
                        Log.InfoFormat("--- {0}  -- Interrupted... bailing out!", _jobKey);
                        throw  new JobExecutionException("Interrupt job"); 
                        //return;
                        // could also choose to throw a JobExecutionException 
                        // if that made for sense based on the particular  
                        // job's responsibilities/behaviors
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                Log.InfoFormat("---- {0} completed at {1}", _jobKey, DateTime.Now.ToString("r"));
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Called by the <see cref="IScheduler" /> when a user
        /// interrupts the <see cref="IJob" />.
        /// </summary>
        public virtual void Interrupt()
        {
            Log.Info("---  -- INTERRUPTING --");
            _interrupted = true;
        }

    }
```

This is my main method.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                LogManager.Adapter = new Common.Logging.Simple.ConsoleOutLoggerFactoryAdapter
                {
                    Level = LogLevel.Info
                };

                // Grab the Scheduler instance from the Factory 
                IScheduler scheduler = GetScheduler();

                //scheduler.Interrupt(@"group1.69decadb-2385-4c30-8d19-22088601670c");
                Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();

                IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<HelloJob>()
                    .WithIdentity(guid.ToString(), "group1")
                    .Build();

                ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                    .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
                    .StartNow()
                    .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                        .WithIntervalInSeconds(10)
                        .RepeatForever()
                        .WithMisfireHandlingInstructionNextWithRemainingCount())
                    .Build();

                var key = job.Key;
                // Tell quartz to schedule the job using our trigger
                scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);

            }
            catch (SchedulerException se)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(se);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close the application");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

The job is fired allright with the right interval times. But, when I send an interrupt, it wont stop the job :(

I am trying to stop the job with

```
IScheduler scheduler = GetScheduler();
var jobkey = new JobKey("69decadb-2385-4c30-8d19-22088601670c","group1");

scheduler.Interrupt(jobkey);
```

I took the job key by using a break-point at the time of job scheduling, saving the key and then test the interrupt. Cross verified from the database.

But even inspite of me sending the interrupt, the job still continues and trigger still fires. I checked this from the `qrtz_simple_triggers` `table.TIMES_TRIGGERED` always increments even after sending an interrupt.

I am not sure what is wrong that I am doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interrupting is meant to be used for running job. It doesn't put the job as a whole to paused state. Job is triggered (counter increments) regardless whether is was interrupted in the middle of processing. Interrupting is meant for long running jobs that need to be signaled to stop - the next run will happen as scheduled.

What you might be looking for is IScheduler.PauseJob(JobKey), this will pause all jobs triggers and thus stopping the execution until triggers are resumed again.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was actually looking for UnscheduleJob, which I found later. My bad, should have removed the question. Thanks for the help. I am still picking up Quartz. Its quite an amazing scheduler.